# Last occurrence in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table in Oracle:

```
ID            Start                  End
AAAAA   20/08/1999 22:12    21/08/1999 00:50
AAAAA   20/08/1999 23:40    21/08/1999 00:51
BBBBB   20/08/1999 20:40    21/08/1999 00:53
AAAAA   21/08/1999 00:51    21/08/1999 01:16
AAAAA   21/08/1999 00:50    21/08/1999 01:20
BBBBB   20/08/1999 21:42    22/08/1999 00:53
```

I'm trying to have this output

```
VALUE   TIMESTAMP
AAAAA   20/08/1999 22:12
0       21/08/1999 01:20
BBBBB   20/08/1999 20:40
0       22/08/1999 00:53
```

ID goes with the FIRST occurrence of Start for each ID and 0 goes wit the LAST occurrence of End for each ID.

I'm using rownum = 1 for the first occurrence but I can't find a way of selecting the LAST occurrence. I tried using COUNT(*) but it's not working well. Can anyone help me?

Code so far:

```
--FIRST ROW ONLY
    select a.Start TIMESTAMP,
           a.ID VALUE
      from MyTable a
     WHERE rownum = 1
--END FIRST COLUMN
     union all 
--LAST ROW COLUMN

    select a.End TIMESTAMP,
           '0' VALUE
      from MyTable a
       --where ???????
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select VALUE, TIMESTAMP
from (
    select min(a.Start) TIMESTAMP,
           a.ID VALUE,
           a.ID,
           1 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID

     union all 

    select max(a.End) TIMESTAMP,
           '0' VALUE,
           a.ID,
           2 ORD
      from MyTable a
      group by a.ID
)
order by ID, ORD
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a strange output.  You can get it using analytic functions:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id else '0' end) as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then start else "end" end) as timestamp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by start) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```